# Compare 4 values in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, compare

I was wondering, if there was a way one can simply do

```
f1.getPlayer()==f2.getPlayer()==f3.getPlayer()!=(byte)0
```

without getting an error for comparing byte with boolean.
All the functions return bytes.

The only option I could come up with was to compare `f1.getPlayer()` to all other objects, but that would be my backup solution if there is truly no other way.

I know, that it would be way easier with arrays, but I wanted to try it without.

Comment: Your option (compare `f1.getPlayer()`)is going to be by far the simplest and most efficient option.  Anything else is going to require at least some arrays.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Thank you but isn't that the way to compare .getPlayer with all other objects?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Do you want to test if at least 1 is not zero?  Do you want to test if none are zero?  Do you want to set a `boolean` based on the result, or put that into an `if` statement?

Comment: If you want to make sure none of them are zero, the most obvious way is `boolean good3 = f1.getPlayer () != 0 && f2.getPlayer () != 0 && f3.getPlayer() != 0;`  (But better design would use an array and a loop so it will be easier to add more Objects of type f1, f2, f3.)

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer I think they need to all be equal *and* be non-zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Java version 8 or above, you can use Streams. Following is an example solution :

```
boolean allMatchAndNonZero = Stream
    .of(f1,f2,f3)
    .allMatch(f -> f.getPlayer() != (byte)0 && f.getPlayer() == f1.getPlayer());
```